# Measure component size in React is incorrect with external stylesheets

Tags: reactjs, dom, stylesheet, dimensions

I am using a simple refCallback to measure the size of a component:

```
<div className="wrapper" ref={(el) => console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect())}>Lorem....</div>
```

This gave incorrect results, compared to the Chrome Dev Tools, so I started digging and found out if I don't load my `App.scss` in my component it showed the correct sizes in the console.

So after a simple check where I removed all the styles from `App.scss` and only added:

```
.wrapper { margin: 0; }
```

I saw that the boundingClientRect was wrong again.

This has to do with Webpack I suppose where the JS is loaded which applies the styles. However, the refCallback is already initiated. Moving it to `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` made no difference, which makes sense. The DOM is loaded, the styles just aren't....

What is the proper way to solve this? Is there a way to check if stylesheets are loaded that it works?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it myself by just adding `document.body.onload` into the `componentDidMount` and handling the sizing in that callback.

```
import '~/somestyles.scss'

class SizeContainer extends React.Component<IProps, any> {

    private ref = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

    componentDidMount(): void {
        document.body.onload = this.onLoad
    }

    onLoad = () => {
        if (this.ref.current) {
            const els = Array.from(this.ref.current!.childNodes);
            els.forEach(el => {
                console.log((el as Element).getBoundingClientRect())
            })
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        return (
            <div ref={this.ref}>
                { children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```